# PnL of a delta-hedged straddle

Tags: options, quant-trading-strategies, option-strategies

On Twitter, this question has been making the rounds:

> If you sold a 30 vol for a one year out at the money straddle, have access to free, perfect, and continuous delta hedging, and stock realizes a 28 vol, have you made money, lost money, or can't be sure?

One user commented that your "pnl is the integral of (implied vol - realized vol) so it depends on the price trajectory." Now, I imagine he's saying that the PnL is like $\int_a^b iv-rv$, so those $a$ and $b$ bounds changes the equation up. However, I thought the entire point of continuously delta hedging was to remove the path dependency? If you're continuously doing this, how is there any price dependency at all? Moreover, why is that the PnL at the end of it all? I lack intuition for this problem, in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I’ll assume a couple of extra details: the option is sold for 30 lognormal vol, then delta hedged according to a Black Scholes model at a 30 vol.  The stock then moves with perfect lognormal Brownian motion with 28 vol.

It is known that if the option were hedged at 28 vol, then indeed all path dependency is theoretically removed and you would realize a profit of $BS(30)-BS(28)$, where $BS()$ refers to the black scholes value at a given vol.  When you instead calculate Greeks using 30vol, you introduce a ‘wrong’ delta which will have an expected pnl of zero but it will be path dependent.

In practice this is all irrelevant because stocks do not follow nice diffusion processes with constant volatilities, but that’s not what the question asks.

Comment: After talking about it with a researcher, a cleaner view might be "developed" by noticing that the PnL of a delta hedged position -- assuming a European call -- under the BS model is roughly 0.5 * gamma * (F^2) * ((daily_return^2) - (vol^2)) * 1/252, and hence it is weighted by (gamma F^2), which introduces the path dependency.

Comment: That’s right but you didn’t ask about daily hedging, you asked about continuous hedging under ideal black scholes conditions.